# Delete operation in SQL with a Join in it

Tags: mysql, sql, join, delete-row, sql-delete

I have two tables, user and ban.  User table has two columns `id` and `type`.  Ban table also has two columns `userID` and `bannedUserID`.  I want to delete records in `ban` table where `bannedUserID` has `type` of 'Admin'.

I've come up with such query but I am not sure if it is correct or not.

`DELETE FROM ban WHERE ban.bannedUserID IN (SELECT id FROM user WHERE type = 'Admin')`

Is it correct? Do I have to add/remove anything?

Comment: looks good to me as well

Comment: Your query seems correct. WHat I wonder about is the usage of two columns, `userID` and `bannedUserID` in table `ban`.

Comment: It contains a user's ban list.  For example, if a row like `12345` and `67890` exists that means User having id `12345` has banned user having id `67890`.  User `12345` won't see any post of user `67890`

Comment: I've ran my own sql and it worked, thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 4):

If you're not sure whether the DELETE is correct, you can test it by converting to an equivalent SELECT:

```
SELECT b.bannedUserID 
FROM ban b JOIN user u ON b.bannedUserID = u.id
WHERE u.type = 'Admin';
```

Are the id's returned by that query the ones you want to DELETE?

Then try it in a transaction (if you use a storage engine that supports transactions, i.e. not MyISAM), so you can roll back if necessary:

```
START TRANSACTION;

DELETE b 
FROM ban b JOIN user u ON b.bannedUserID = u.id
WHERE u.type = 'Admin';

/* do some SELECT to see if the correct rows have been deleted and no others */
/* but if anything appears wrong, and ban is an InnoDB table, you can... */

ROLLBACK;
```

Note that I'm using MySQL's multi-table DELETE syntax.  It should work identically to your subquery approach, but in some cases it can be more flexible.